# Is it possible not to reuse a specific cell in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to put some special effect in first row of `UITableView` but when i scroll down the table view it comes with other cells as well(because cell reusability?). So is there any way that i prevent any specific cell from reuse?I tried with passing `nil` as reusableIndentifier for first cell but it gives me error(insertion failure).

I'm calling this method from `viewDidApper` method for some animation on first row-

```
-(void)openSubmenuForFirstRow{

    stIndex = 0;
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
    StoreCell* sCell = (StoreCell *)cell;

    UIView* mainView = [sCell viewWithTag:101];
    UIView* subView = [sCell viewWithTag:102];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

        CGRect rect = subView.frame;
        rect.origin.x = 0;
        subView.frame = rect;

        CGRect mainViewRect = mainView.frame;
        mainViewRect.origin.x = 117;
        mainView.frame = mainViewRect;
    }];

}
```

but i get this animation on several other cells when i scroll the table view.
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: it should work if you use a different `reusableIndentifier` for those cells. The reusableIndentifier is to name the kind of the cells.. so you always get the correct ones.

Comment: where are you calling openSubmenuForFirstRow?

Comment: @mxb as i mentioned in question in 'viewDidAppear' method

Comment: You refer to the first row,  it your code accesses the cell for row 1, which is the second row. Row 0 is the first row. Also, you should check to see if the cell returned by `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is nil - as this indicates that the cell is no longer on the screen.

Comment: I'v posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696109/issue-while-reusing-table-view-cell) related to this please check.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two cell CellIdentifires. One is for first row and second for others. Check for indexPath.row. If it is 0 use the cellidentifier1 otherwise cellidentifier2.

Use it for first row:

```
 UITableViewCell* cell;
 if(indexPath.row == 0){
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell1"];
 }
 else{
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2"];
 }
 if (cell == nil) {
      if(indexPath.row == 0){
             cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell1"];
      }
      else{
           cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell2"];
      }
 }
```

Comment: so for this approach do i need to design two cells in storyboard?

Comment: initWithFrame was first deprecated in iOS 3.0, will this work now?

Comment: You need to use initWithStyle instead of initWithFrame and also you need to design two cells with different cellIdentifiers.

Comment: Yes i did that, but now if open menu in other row and scroll table it gives me same problem

Comment: I'v posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696109/issue-while-reusing-table-view-cell) related to this please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the menu only when the first cell is displayed. Remove the call from `viewDidAppear` and add this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [self openSubmenuForCell: cell];
    }
}
```

You'll also need to change your method as follow:

```
- (void)openSubmenuForCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell {

    stIndex = 0;
    StoreCell* sCell = (StoreCell *)cell;

    UIView* mainView = [sCell viewWithTag:101];
    UIView* subView = [sCell viewWithTag:102];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

        CGRect rect = subView.frame;
        rect.origin.x = 0;
        subView.frame = rect;

        CGRect mainViewRect = mainView.frame;
        mainViewRect.origin.x = 117;
        mainView.frame = mainViewRect;
    }];

}
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not show menu fist time when table appears, menu shows after i scroll the table but still the same problem, many rows are showing menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for register cell :

```
 NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell  *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
```

and where objectAtIndex is your custom cell tag.