# Issue while reusing table view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my `UITableView` i'v added swipe `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to cell. so when i swipe on any cell it opens a menu on that row.But when i scroll the table view due to cell reusability the menu appears on other cells down the table also.But i want to show menu only on row which was swiped by user.
Here is my code -

```
-(StoreCell *)configureCellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath table:(UITableView *)tablev{

    UITableViewCell* cell;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StoreCell";

    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    StoreCell* stCell = (StoreCell *)cell;
    stCell.delegate = self;
   //configure my cell here

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* gestureR = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [gestureR setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [stCell addGestureRecognizer:gestureR];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* gestureL = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLeftSwipeFrom:)];
    [gestureL setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [stCell addGestureRecognizer:gestureL];

    return stCell;
}
```

So how to achieve the desired behaviour so that menu should appear only on one row not reused cell.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Store the index path of the cell that currently has the menu open, if the cell being drawn isn't of that index path don't show the menu

Comment: Also why are you creating a UITableViewCell, then initialising it on another row and then casting it to a different class?

Comment: I copied this code from other place where i have more cells, so i defined cell on top and later initialise it according to indexpath.

Comment: @CW0007007 thanks for your reply, i implemented as your suggestion but now it doesn't show menu on swiped cell after scrolling?

Comment: i didn't make a suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep in a varible the cell that was swiped. And after You do something like:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

if(indexPath.row = self.swipedRow){
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellSwiped";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
            autorelease];


   cell.textLabel.text=[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}else{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellNotSwiped";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
            autorelease];


   cell.textLabel.text=[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

I didnt test the code but I think you can understand the idea ;) I hope I could help

Comment: Thanks Ricardo i have solved the problem by maintaining indexpath of swiped cell.

Answer (score 0):

- I don't know about the whole logic of your code. Whatever it is,
- You have added the gestures to the cell in **if** condition but **else** is missing, so while reuse it will be replicating.
- to avoid this you may set **nil** to the cell's gesturerecognizer in the **else** part of your code, refer below. I jus copied and pasted your code in the **else** part, the only change is **gesture**.

-(StoreCell *)configureCellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath table:(UITableView *)tablev{

```
UITableViewCell* cell;
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StoreCell";
if(indexPath.row == 1){

    /* ---- Your Code ---  */

    return stCell;
}
else{

    /* ---- Your Code ---  */

[stCell setGestureRecognizers:nil];
    return stCell;

}}
```